# Can you Fill a global Numpy Array with multiple cores in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to multicore programming with Python.
So first this is an example code, that shows my problem:

```
numpyarray = np.zero((100, 100))

def myMainFunction(x, y, t, data):
    global numpyarray

    x += t
    numpyarray[x][y]+=data


for line in myDict:
    x = myDict[line]['pos']['x']
    y = myDict[line]['pos']['y']

    digit = 0

    for data in FD[line]['data']:
        digit += 1
        t = otherFunction(digit)

        myMainFunction(x, y, t, data)
```

So my two main problems are, that I have a global variable, the numpy array, that i want to fill parallel and that i have more than variable for the myMainFunction that i wanna run parallel. 
Anyone an Idea how tu run this parallel, because the code takes a lot of time..

Comment: If you are using `multiprocessing`, then the different processes *do not share state*.

Comment: You can do this with threads (e.g., a `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`). You should read the NumPy docs on thread safety; but this code does happen to be threadsafe. However, you’re not going to get much speedup out of it. Each task (each call to `myMainFunction` is doing very little work, and none of it is NumPy-vectorized work, so almost all of your time will be spent fighting over the Global Interpreter Lock.

Comment: You can fix the GIL problem by using multiprocessing instead, with an explicit shared-memory (or np.memmap) array, but that’s a bit more complicated (you really need to read the docs—and have a basic understanding of C-level memory), but then you’re adding a lot of overhead to each task, and the fact that your tasks are so tiny means the overhead will probably swamp any gain.

Comment: So, what you need to do here is find some way to vectorize the array filling. That in itself might make your code as much as 20x faster. But it also opens the door to parallelizing it effectively, so an 8-code machine can go almost 8x faster than that.

Comment: The slow thing here isn't assigning values to the array, even if you do `arr[x,y]` (though better if you can assign major blocks at once).  It's iterating through several layers of dictionary.

Comment: `numpyarray` doesn't have to be marked `global` is you are modifying elements.

Comment: hpaulj I dont think so, because I iterate throught the same dict in another program the same way, and i also checked my code with cprofile.  the: numpyarray[x][y]+=data , is what needs most of the time..  

Hey @abarnert thank you for your suggestions. What do you mean with vectorizing the array filling?  can you give me an example ?

Comment: Vectorizing means doing operations on a whole array, or at least a whole slice of it, at a time, instead of looping over one element at a time. For example, `arr *= 2` instead of `for i in range(arr.shape[0]): for j in range(arr.shape[1])): arr[i,j] *= 2`. Of course under the covers numpy still needs a loop to implement that `arr *= 2`, but it's tightly-optimized, cache-friendly, possibly even SIMD-assisted loop written in C, which is much faster than a Python `for` loop.